# How can I iterate through an array of multiple objects showing n number of objects at a time in an element in javascript react

Tags: javascript

Here's an example of the object

```
const ArrOfObj = [{letter: "A"},{letter: "B"},{letter: "C"}]
```

I'm currently using the Carousel component in React-Bootstrap and I want to render two objects in a single Carousel Item.

I'm able to do it by adding the properties of the array manually but that would have too much repeating code and it is not scalable at all.

So the first carousel item/slide should have 2 objects including 'A', and 'B' and the second carousel item/slide should have the letter 'C'

Here's an example of what it would look like if I added in manually

```
<Carousel>
 <Carousel.Item>
  <div className="row">
   <div className="col-6">
    //"A" should be here
   </div>
   <div className="col-6">
    //"B" should be here
   </div>
  </div>
 </Carousel.Item>
 <Carousel.Item>
  <div className="row">
   <div className="col-6">
    //"C" should be here
   </div>
  </div>
 </Carousel.Item>
</Carousel>
```

As one of the comment mentioned, yes, I am aware that I am supposed to use loops/iteration to solve it. However, I'm not too sure on what steps I should be doing to accomplish the goal.

Comment: [Loops/iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).

Comment: Yup. I do know I'm supposed to use loops/iteration. However, I'm not really sure what the steps I should be taking to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leave React out of this and posit the question as "how to chunk an array".

```
// Example chunk function:
const chunk = (arr, size) =>
  Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(arr.length / size) }, (v, i) =>
    arr.slice(i * size, i * size + size)
  );
console.log(chunk([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2));

// Output:
[[1,2],[3,4],[5]]
```

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't really know how to word the questions. This is a great help!